# React: conditional rendering for To-Do app

Tags: reactjs

Working on my To Do app in React and need help with the following:

Here is my array of task objects with true of false statuses:

```
    let todoList = [
        {description:"Buy new sweatshirt", status: true},
        {description:"Go for a walk", status: false},
    ]
```

Here is my current array rendering function:

```
return <div>
{todoList.map((task) => {
   return <ul> 
        <li className="style1" key={task.description}>{task.description}</li>
   </ul> 
})}
</div>
```

**Question**: how do I implement a logic where React will be rendering array description values differently (e.g. different className) based on their status value? Something like:

```
if (todoList.status == true){
// className="style1"
<ul> 
    <li className="style1" key={task.description}>{task.description}</li>
</ul> 
} else {
// className="style2"
<ul> 
    <li className="style2" key={task.description}>{task.description}</li>
</ul> 
}
```

Comment: This is pretty well documented under [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to put the condition inside your `map` function, so that it gets run for each item of the array. Also, you don't need to duplicate the entire element for each branch - just conditionally set the class name.

```js
// You probably don't want to be rendering a new `ul` for each item!
return <ul> 
  {todoList.map(task => {
    let className = task.status ? "style1" : "style2";
    return <li className={className} key={task.description}>{task.description}</li>;
  })}
</ul>;
```